# Maximum number of positive roots is $3$

Tags: co.combinatorics, polynomials, differential-equations, recurrences, exponential-sums

Let $$f(x) = a+b(x+p)^t+c(x+p)^t(x+q)^t+d(x+p)^t(x+q)^t(x+r)^t,$$
where $t>1$ is any positive real number, $p>q>r>0$  or  $p<q<r$ are positive integers and $a,b,c,d$ are any arbitrary real numbers which are not simultaneously zero.

**Que:** Prove that,

$1.$ $f(x)$ has at most $3$ positive zeros.

$2.$ $f(x)$ has at most $3$ positive integer zeros.

I need $2$ actually, but I think $1$ is also true.

**My attempts:**

I tried to show that $f'(x)$ has at most two positive zeros so that by Rolle's Theorem, the result follows, but the expression for $f'(x)$ is not fruitful.

**Note: This question is also on Mathstackexchange, (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4155919/does-this-function-have-at-most-3-positive-zeros).**

Kindly suggest any help or tip. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Relevant theorem perhaps? https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Skolem%E2%80%93Mahler%E2%80%93Lech_theorem

Comment: How is it relevant? I am not sure.

Comment: Is my approach (2) wrong?

Comment: @Matt.F, the question has been edited.

Comment: Where does this problem come from, please?

Comment: Why both (1) *and* (2), when "at most 3 positive zeroes" implies "at most 3 positive integer zeroes"?

Comment: If $x_1<x_2<x_3<x_4$ are solutions, then the determinant $$\begin{vmatrix}
1 & (x_1+p)^t & (x_1+p)^t(x_1+q)^t & (x_1+p)^t(x_1+q)^t(x_1+r)^t \\
1 & (x_2+p)^t & (x_2+p)^t(x_2+q)^t & (x_2+p)^t(x_2+q)^t(x_2+r)^t \\
1 & (x_3+p)^t & (x_3+p)^t(x_3+q)^t & (x_3+p)^t(x_3+q)^t(x_3+r)^t \\
1 & (x_4+p)^t & (x_4+p)^t(x_4+q)^t & (x_4+p)^t(x_4+q)^t(x_4+r)^t
\end{vmatrix}$$will be 0. But for $t=1$ the determinant is $\Pi_{i<j}(x_i-x_j)$, which is positive; and according to Mathematica the determinant is at least non-negative for $t=2,3,4,5$. Can we prove that the determinant is always positive for $t>1$?

Comment: @Matt,  what if we know that for integers t, this det is nonzero? Will it be helpful?

Comment: @prince, what I know from logic (o-minimality of $\exp$) is that if $\det>0$ for all positive integer $t$, then $\det>0$ for all *sufficiently large* real $t$. I don't see any quick arguments to get that implication for all real $t$, but maybe it would follow from some complex analysis.

Comment: @Matt, have you got anything? You must see the comments here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4155919/does-this-function-have-at-most-3-positive-zeros

Answer (score 1):

> **Claim 1:** $f$ has $\le3$ positive roots if $t\ge1$ and $p,q,r$ are integers such that $0<p<q<r$.

> **Claim 2:** $f$ has $\le3$ positive roots if $t\ge2$ and $p,q,r$ are integers such that $p>q>r>0$.

Let
$$f_1(x):=\frac{f'(x)}{(p+x)^{t-1}},$$
$$f_2(x):=\frac{f_1'(x)}{(q+x)^{t-2}(q + p (t-1) + q t + 2 t x)},$$
$$f_3(x):=\frac{f_2'(x)}{t(r+x)^{t-3}}\,(q + p (t-1) + q t + 2 t x)^2.$$

If $d=0$, then $f_2(x)=ct$. So, if $c\ne0$, then $f_2$ has no positive roots, and hence $f_1$ has $\le1$ positive roots, so that $f$ has $\le2\le3$ positive roots. If $d=0=c$, then $f(x)=a+b(x+p)^t$, so that $f$ has $\le1\le3$ positive roots, because $|a|+|b|\ne0$.

It remains to consider the case $d\ne0$.

Consider the case when $t\ge1$ and $p,q,r$ are positive integers such that $0<p<q<r$, as in Claim 1.
Then, letting $S:=t-1[\ge0]$, $P:=p-1[\ge0]$, $Q:=q-p-1[\ge0]$, and $R:=r-q-1[\ge0]$, we see that $f_3(x)/d$ is a polynomial in $x,S,P,Q,R$ with all coefficients nonnegative and a positive free term. So, $f_3$ has no positive roots, and hence $f_2$ has $\le1$ positive roots, and hence $f_1$ has $\le2$ positive roots, so that $f$ has $\le3$ positive roots. This completes the proof of Claim 1.

Consider now the case when $t\ge2$ and $p,q,r$ are positive integers such that $p>q>r>0$, as in Claim 2.
Then, letting $S:=t-2[\ge0]$, $P:=p-q-1[\ge0]$, $Q:=q-r-1[\ge0]$, and  $R:=r-1[\ge0]$, we see that $f_3(x)/d$ is a polynomial in $x,S,P,Q,R$ with all coefficients nonnegative. So, $f_3$ has no positive roots, and hence $f_2$ has $\le1$ positive roots, and hence $f_1$ has $\le2$ positive roots, so that $f$ has $\le3$ positive roots. This completes the proof of Claim 2.

---

Here are details of the calculations, with Mathematica (click on the images to enlarge them):

[image]

[image]

Comment: @losif, thanks for replying. Please tell, are you using any software like Mathematica, to find these derivatives?

Comment: @prince : Yes, I used Mathematica for calculations, as stated in the answer.